# Intellij idea - Show parameters names on structure view

Tags: intellij-idea, parameters

In Intellij's structure view I see a list of methods and the their parameters types. I would prefer to see (also) the parameters names, since "partnerId" is more useful to me than just "String".

Comment: As a workaround you could open "Quick Documentation" shortcut to see  parameter name. Also feel  free to create feature request on YouTrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful!